# Mono compilation error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I get the following compilation error in Monodevelop:

> Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>
> 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<AudioBitrateCalculationStream>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AudioBitrateCalculationStream>)' and
>
> 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<AudioBitrateCalculationStream>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AudioBitrateCalculationStream>)' (CS0121)

Both definitions are exactly the same. I cannot understand what the issue is. Internet search does not help.

Comment: check the References. You might have 2 assemblies providing a definition for the ToArray() extension method.

Comment: I would suggest to remove one of those USING <your reference> and write the full namespace instead. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. It was extra include. The build passed when I commented out that reference in the .csproj file.